# Задержки при ожидание ответа (Dataflow)

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl-dataflow

В программе необходимо в **отдельном** потоке проводить некоторые операции, как **например** отправлять запрос серверу и **ждать** от него ответ.
 Для реализации использую **библиотеку** `Dataflow`, дабы выполнять это всё последовательно. 
**Реализовал такой класс:**

```
partial class PoolManager
{
    CancellationTokenSource CT;
    TransformBlock<Func<string>, string> ActionBlock;

    public PoolManager()
    {
        PM = this;
        CT = new CancellationTokenSource();
        ActionBlock = new TransformBlock<Func<string>, string>(async n =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            string a = "";
            try
            {
                a =  n();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
            return a;
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { CancellationToken = CT.Token });
    }

    public void Add(Action func, string message)
    {
        ActionBlock.Post(new Func<string>(delegate () { func(); return message; }));
    }
}
```

И целом работает как нужно, **но** когда я посылаю в него функцию, внутри которой есть отправка и ожидание ответа, то на моменте ожидания, интерфейс программы подвисает. В **среднем** это *100мс*, иногда доходит и до *500мс* или *1000мс*, что становится очень заметно. Не понимаю в чём причина, ибо он в отдельном потоке **должен** идти.

Comment: Не похоже, что проблема в приведенном коде. Мне кажется, вам стоит искать где-то уровнем выше. P.S. Зачем вам вообще Dataflow для одного шага?

Comment: @andreycha Я просмотрел всю иерархию вызываемых функций которые смог, и всё заканчивается на синхронной функции, которая делает запрос и возвращает Json строку. И именно там задержка. 

В тех функциях которые я отправляю в Dataflow блок, больше одного шага.

Comment: @andreycha: Dataflow наверное посоветовал я в каком-то из комментариев.

Comment: @VladD , да. Для моей задачи он и вправду поудобнее.

Comment: @BwehaaFox: А какая у вас «точка входа»? Что вы запускаете, после чего программа подвисает?

Comment: @VladD Небольшой оффтоп. Не могу понять смысла DataFlow, если на async/await точно так же задача дробится на очередь тасков, которая перемалывается потоками из пула на всех ядрах.

Comment: @vitidev: Смысл DataFlow в том, что вы как бы выстраиваете сеть сложной геометрии заранее, и пропускаете через неё данные. То есть как бы сначала выстраиваете трубы, а потом по ним течёт вода. А в async/await у вас построение геометрии обработки и сама обработка данных слиты в один код.

Comment: @VladD Что имеется ввиду под "точкой входа"? . При нажатии на кнопку, она посылает функцию в этот класс в очередь. Функция которую я отправляю построена примерно следующим образом. Она обрабатывает строку и после этого посылает запрос на сервер и возвращает объекты, после чего заполняется деление прогрессбара. Таких запросов в среднем 3-4 штуки и подвисает именно во время ожидания получения ответа.

Comment: @BwehaaFox: Ну, при нажатии на кнопку вызывается функция `public void Add(Action func, string message)`, правильно?

Comment: @BwehaaFox: А если временно закомментировать строку `if (TaskAddedEvent != null) TaskAddedEvent();`, то всё ещё подвисает? (Я пытаюсь выяснить, какая из двух строк функции `Add` представляет собой проблему).

Comment: @BwehaaFox: Ещё один эксперимент — а что если превратить функцию из `TransformBlock` в не-async для теста? То есть убрать async и `await Task.Delay` заменить на `Thread.Sleep()`?

Comment: Стойте, вы упоминали функцию, в которой «внутри есть отправка и ожидание ответа». Что это за функция? Это должно быть важно.

Comment: @VladD интерфейс подвисает не на Task.Delay, поэтому разницы особо и нету(проверил).  Нашел как откопать где происходит реализация интерфеса запроса, прошел пошагово в отладке и вот в этом куске кода как я понял и происходит задержка using (var requestStream = call.Request.GetRequestStream()) .  Сама отправка как я понял базируется на System.Net.WebRequest

Comment: @VladD Наглядно можно посмотреть тут как реализовано: [Вот здесь](https://github.com/vknet/vk/blob/master/VkNet/Utils/WebCall.cs) В данном случае используется функция `PostCall`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37178/discussion-between-bwehaafox-and-vladd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Вопрос решился сам собой.**

---

В целом данный код работает вполне корректно, и проблема таилась глубже.
В конкретной **задаче** на которой я тестировал этот код, в `TransformBlock` отправлялась функция находящаяся в элементе управления `UserControl`.
В этой функции вызывался метод экземпляра класса, и этот метод посылал запрос на сервер и ожидал ответа. Метод был **синхронный** и потому поток в котором он вызывался должен был **блокироваться**. Для того, что бы этого не было делал это в паралельном потоке, но основной поток всё равно блокировался.

В итоге я **обратил внимание**, что код в посылаемой функции выполяется через `Dispatcher`, дабы я мог выполнять заполнение `ProgressBar`, и следовательно **проверив** номер потока через `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`, при входе в функцию и в диспетчер, понял что код внутри `Dispatcher` выполняется в уже в потоке ***UI***, а не в потоке `TransformBlock`, от того запрос и проходил в потоке ***UI***, что и вызывало подвисание.
Спасибо [**VladD**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/141055/vladd), за **помощь** в решении данной проблемы.